# Disable/enable Jenkins plugin per job/node

Tags: jenkins, hudson, hudson-plugins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to disable/enable plugin per job or slave node?

I'm looking for a way to do that because jenkins admin in my company has concerns about security issues come with groovy system plugin and wants to disable the plugin for all jobs but mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the original question, the way to hide something is to create a class which extends **hudson.model.DescriptorVisibilityFilter**, and overrides filter() method, which can then perform arbitrary hiding. I'm pretty sure it will also work on build steps. I don't know of an existing plugin which would do this in a configurable way, so it's probably time to learn some Jenkins plugin coding, if you want this.

But, with system groovy build step this is not very useful, as explained by Vladimir above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such feature and a quick search showed nothing.

However, quoted from the [Groovy plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin): *only users with **admin rights** can  add system groovy build step and configure the system groovy script*

If your admin is not comfortable enough with you having the admin rights for the Jenkins, he must be able to set up a separate Jenkins master server just for you and your jobs.